# How to remove a line from a file in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file that named `tmp` that contains 4 strings:

```
dirs
f1
f2
f3
```

I want to stay with

```
f1
f2
f3
```

What bash command helps me to accomplish this? (Only bash please, no sed or awk.)

Comment: Read line by line and exclude a line if desired; otherwise, write to a temp file and finally replace the original file with it.

Comment: can you show me an example? @BlueMoon

Comment: OK. Need a bit more detail. Why are sed/awk excluded? Depending on what you're actually trying to exclude - is it based on line number or line content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
grep -v "dirs" tmp
```

The `-v` argument of `grep` will negate the match, i.e. it will exclude anything matching `dirs` from the file `tmp`

Or if you wanted a pure `bash` solution:

```
while read -r line
do
  if ! [[ $line =~ "dirs" ]]
  then
    echo $line
  fi
done < tmp
```

Comment: If `sed` and `awk` are disallowed, I'm not sure why `grep` would be ok?

Comment: Why bother with a regular expression to match a literal string? Seems wasteful.

Comment: @kojiro purely because I was emulating the grep command in bash

Comment: @arco444 well, not to belabor the point, but `grep` by itself will use BRE, but `=~` will use ERE, so you're emulating `egrep` when you probably only need `fgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways is using *tail*:

```
tail -n 3 tmp
```

Comment: yes i thought of this but i font know how many lines I will have

Comment: i gave one example of 4 lines, but it might be 5, but what i can tell you that i know that the line that i dont want always will be the first line

Answer (score 0):

regular expression with grep: either

**grep 'f' tmp > name_of_output_file**

or

**grep '[^"dirs"]' tmp > name_of_output_file**

work for me